# How to Switch Widgets after certain time in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-animation, flutter-animation

I am facing problems with this tematic, I would like to change a widget after certain time. e.g
I have this animatedFlutter Screen (screen 1) and then after the animation end I would like to change the screen to any screen that I have, for example. Login();

Any tips? Thanks.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() => runApp(AnimatedFlutterLogo());

class AnimatedFlutterLogo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _AnimatedFlutterLogoState();

}

class _AnimatedFlutterLogoState extends State<AnimatedFlutterLogo> {
  Timer _timer;
  FlutterLogoStyle _logoStyle = FlutterLogoStyle.markOnly;

  _AnimatedFlutterLogoState() {
    _timer = new Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 800), () {
      setState(() {
        _logoStyle = FlutterLogoStyle.horizontal;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _timer.cancel();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new FlutterLogo(
      size: 200.0,
      textColor: Colors.white,
      style: _logoStyle,

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this,

```
_Act_NotificationScreenState() {
_timer = new Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 800), () {
  setState(() {
    _logoStyle = FlutterLogoStyle.horizontal;
  });
  _timer = new Timer(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Act_Login()));
  });
});
}
```

Comment: This work fine, thanks. By the way is there  a way to "clean" the screen 1? I mean, when the screen 2 appears I want that the previous buttom (buttom that apears in most of the cellphone (physic buttom)) goes to home screen and not screen 1 app

Comment: try this, **Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Act_Login()));**

Comment: Oh my god! It work excellent. Thanks for help flutter community :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write code of navigating to another screen (Widget in case of Flutter)

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()),
  );
```

You need to import Login in your current screen.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `AnimatedFlutterLogo` with `MaterialApp` and in the callback function of Timer use `Navigator` to navigate to respective Page

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home:AnimatedFlutterLogo()));

class AnimatedFlutterLogo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _AnimatedFlutterLogoState();

}

class _AnimatedFlutterLogoState extends State<AnimatedFlutterLogo> {
  Timer _timer;
  FlutterLogoStyle _logoStyle = FlutterLogoStyle.markOnly;

  _AnimatedFlutterLogoState() {
    _timer = new Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 800), () {
       setState(() {
        _logoStyle = FlutterLogoStyle.horizontal;
      });
    Navigator.push(                      //<-- Navigate to loginPage on Timeout
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()),
  );
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _timer.cancel();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new FlutterLogo(
      size: 200.0,
      textColor: Colors.white,
      style: _logoStyle,

    );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Container(alignment: Alignment.center,child: Text("LOG IN PAGE"));
  }
}
```

Comment: the second screen appears faster than the logo animation, anyways it works.

Comment: That's because you are changing the logo inside the Timeout callback function

Comment: You can use  `AnimationController` to achieve the desired animationo

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I marked your answer as useful but system says " Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."